# What is the best way to get output from a 2 layer loop for 2D array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

```
var myArray = {}; 
myArray["abc"] = new Array();
myArray["def"] = new Array();
myArray["abc"][0] = "John";
myArray["abc"][1] = "Mary"; 
myArray["abc"][2] = "Jack";  
var letter = "";
var id = "";

for (var i_letter in myArray)    {                
        for (var j_id = 0; j_id < myArray[i_letter].length; j_id++)  {                   
                if (myArray[i_letter][j_id]=== "Mary")  {
                      letter = i_letter;   // error ?
                      id = j_id;   // error?
                }
        }
}
document.write( letter + “ , ” + id);   // why error?  Suppose to be “abc , 1”
```

What is the best way to get output, namely i_letter and j_id, from outside the loop?
By the way, if myArray contains huge data, is there anyway to write codes more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at my comment :

```
var myArray = new Array(); // error here
myArray["abc"] = new Array();
myArray["def"] = new Array();
myArray["abc"][0] = "John";
myArray["abc"][1] = "Mary"; 
myArray["abc"][2] = "Jack";  
var letter = '';
var id = '';

myLoop: // initial point of breaking outer for
for (i_letter in myArray) {               
        for (j_id=0; j_id < myArray[i_letter].length; j_id++)  {                   
                if (myArray[i_letter][j_id] === "Mary")  {
                      letter = i_letter;   
                      id = j_id;
                      break myLoop; // break from two for
                }
        }
}
document.write( letter + ' , ' + id); // error here because of using “ and ”
```

The best way for this case is to set initial point of loop `myLoop`, and when Mary is found just stop executing `for` by doing `break myLoop`.

Demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dirgagautama/53NxN/1/).

Hopefully this help.

Comment: If this solves the problem please mark it as accepted answer otherwise it would unnecessarily remain open.